# Dynamically written DataGridView columns ReadOnly Property is not working

Tags: c#, datagridview, readonly

I am writing the ReadOnly Property to true in form load as

```
dgvDcNon.Columns["itemDiscrip"].ReadOnly = true;
```

but the property is not working. Should i do any more steps to implement this?

Iam setting autocomplete mode to the datagridview in editingcontrolshowing event. Is it any cause for that.?
my code is

```
           if (e.Control is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tbValid = e.Control as TextBox;
                tbValid.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(tbValid_KeyPress);
            }
            String[] strAutoCmp = prodctsDCCls.AutoCmpltPrdct();
            TextBox txtAuto = e.Control as TextBox;
            txtAuto.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            txtAuto.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

            if (this.dgvDcNon.Columns[this.dgvDcNon.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "itemDiscrip")
            {
                var name = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                name.AddRange(strAutoCmp);
                if (txtAuto != null)
                {
                    txtAuto.AutoCompleteCustomSource = name;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                txtAuto.AutoCompleteCustomSource = null;
            }
```

Comment: What exactly is happening? You can still change value in the cell of that column?

Comment: Yes. Exaclty sir @yBee

Comment: Try using the Index of the column, see if that makes a difference. This should work fine. e.g dgvDcNon.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;

Comment: Are you sure that there is no place in your code that could override that value?

Comment: Yahh.. there are no overrides for that. Iam sure

Comment: @Derek : tried with columns[0]. still not working

Comment: Do you have any custom columns that have Data Members?

Comment: I see two options. 1. There is a bug in *DataGridView*. 2. There is a place (may be implicit) where the value of *ReadOnly* is overriden. Are you setting that value after connecting to a data source?

Comment: You need to show your code, I think there's a something your doing wrong, but I need more of you code.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that your setting an AutoComplete cell read only cell? That doesnt make any sense? If i'm reading that code right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be related to the data source ?
If the datasource is read-only, then you cannot change this.

**EDITED**

If you use a database model for this, EX:

```
Class Item
{
    public string itemId {get; set;}
    public string itemName {get; set;}
    public string itemDiscrip {get; set;}
    public int itemSize {get; set;}
    //whatever
}
```

Try to remove the setter from your code:

```
public int itemSize {get; set;}
```

should become

```
public int itemSize {get;}
```

If you have other type of datasource, try using the readonly modifier.

Comment: Should I set read only to the datasource?? If soo.. how to set readonly to the datasource. my datasource is datatable

Comment: It depends on how you read your datasource. If you have a database model, try removing the setter from that property